# Python Tkinter Program is crashing with forget()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, crash, tkinter

In my Program I want to use `forget()` on a button. Now if I try that, the program crashes. I know that it has something to do with threading but I couldn't find a soultion yet. Thanks in advance. Here is my examplecode:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import thread

window = tk.Tk()

def ok():
    pass

    def voice():
        button1.forget()
        print("If you see this, it works!")

    thread.start_new_thread(voice,())

button1=tk.Button(command=ok, text="PRESS")
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Accessing a widget in a thread other than the one that created it, tends to make Tkinter flip out and crash. Why use threading at all here? just make the Button's command `voice` directly.

Comment: @kevin Well, this is just an example code. In my real Program I use pyttsx and for this I need threading.

Comment: Perhaps you could refactor your code so that all Tkinter-specific actions take place on the main thread. For example, voice sets a global `should_forget` to True, and the root has an `after_idle` callback method which periodically checks if `should_forget` becomes True, and calls `forget` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem simply by using the module `mtTkinter` , which you can find here :
http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/mtTkinter To use it you only have to write `import mtTkinter as Tkinter` at the beginning. After that you can use your Tkinter normally. This module changes nothing in Tkinter, it only makes it thread-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access tkinter objects from any thread but the thread that creates the object. In other words, you can't call `button1.forget()` from a thread and expect it to work reliably.

The generally accepted solution is to have your thread(s) write information to a thread-safe queue, and have your GUI thread poll that queue perioducally, pull an item off, and do whatever that item is requesting.

Comment: So what can I do to get around the problem?

Comment: @Duardo: I've updated my answer slightly. If you search this site there are examples of this solution.

Answer (score -1):

Tkinter is notorious for the fact that its lack of thread safety means that code you have written can sometimes work, and sometimes cause the entire program to hang with no errors produced, which is a pain.

Luckily, Tkinter does have its own measure for dealing with the problem, so to start a a thread with voice in it, just call voice. However, at theend of voice make sure you have made use of the window.after method to call it again later down the line. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import thread

window = tk.Tk()

def ok():
    pass

    def voice():
        button1.forget()
        print("If you see this, it works!")
        window.after(10, voice())

    voice()

button1=tk.Button(command=ok, text="PRESS")
button1.pack()

window.mainloop(
```

Comment: the original question doesn't run anything on a timer, so I don't think adding a timer is going to solve anything.

Comment: He posted code that wanted to make use of multi-threading and tkinter, which is quite simply not possible. I took the liberty of assuming that his ultimate goal would be to have something running at the same time as the main thread, else what is the point in using threading. The solution I have posted presents all the information he could possibly need for however he decided to implement his program. It is up to him to decide how he uses it.